# Item Template in the ItemPresenter

Tags: silverlight, templates

In this template ItemPresenter just defines host panel for the Items. 
Is it possible to define ItemTemplate?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ItemsControlTemplate" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsPresenter Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

To go further, I've created a class:

```
public class ItemsControlExtended : ItemsControl
{
    public ItemsControlExtended()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ItemsControlExtended);
    }
}
```

And I would like to create a dependency property "ItemsMargin".
After I've done that I'm supposed to bind an Item "Margin" property to "ItemsMargin".
How it would be possible to implement?

GetContainerForItemOverride ? 
PrepareContainerForItemOverride ?
OnApplyTemplate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the ItemTemplate from with the `ControlTemplate` for the control as a whole.

Instead you would create a style that includes your control template and the the other templates as required:-

```
 <Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
              <!-- your template as above -->
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>

   <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <!-- An alternative to StackPanel if so desired -->
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>


   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
          <DatalTemplate>
              <!-- The item template you wanted -->
          </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>

</Style>
```

Now you can style the ItemsControl:-

```
<ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}">
```